# Use a Row as title in FlexibleSpaceBar [Flutter]

Tags: flutter

I would like to use a Row widget instead of a Text widget as the title for the FlexibleSpaceBar.
Unfortunately Flutter returns an error.
Here is my code:

```
CustomScrollView(
          slivers: [
            const SliverAppBar(
              pinned: true,
              floating: false,
              backgroundColor: Color(0xFF172A3A),
              snap: false,
              expandedHeight: 200,
              centerTitle: true,
              flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                background: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('Demo'),
                  ]
                ),
                centerTitle: true,
              ),
            ),
            SliverFixedExtentList(
              itemExtent: 50.0,
              delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    color: Colors.lightBlue[100 * (index % 9)],
                    child: Text('List Item $index'),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

I know that the title should be a Text widget but I actually need a Row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
Step 1 : Remove `const` keyword in front of `SliverAppBar` 
Step 2 : Use `Row` like this

```
title: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text('title'),
                  Text('test'),
                ]),
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: [
          SliverAppBar(
            pinned: true,
            floating: false,
            backgroundColor: Color(0xFF172A3A),
            snap: false,
            expandedHeight: 200,
            centerTitle: true,
            title: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text('title'),
                  Text('test'),
                ]),
            flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
              background: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('Demo'),
                  ]),
              centerTitle: true,
            ),
          ),
          SliverFixedExtentList(
            itemExtent: 50.0,
            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
              (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  color: Colors.lightBlue[100 * (index % 9)],
                  child: Text('List Item $index'),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```